# Animation in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, collada

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am making an animation of smoke using Blender 2.5s' particle system.

1. Is it possible to import that animation in Gazebo?
2. How will the laser behave to that smoke whether it is going to consider it particles or surrounding box?
3. If it is not possible what could be the best way to simulate smoke in Gazebo?

Thanks.
(p.s I am using ubuntu 10.04 and ROS electric)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67579/animation-in-gazebo/) by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest that you take this up on http://answers.gazebosim.org

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1